# Loading URL directly VS Loading URLLoader

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to load a php file from my server, loading the PHP's URL directly gives me instant results however loading it using as3 URLLoader takes around 15 seconds. I have no idea why nor what im doing wrong... any ideas?

this is how I'm coding it

```
// Build the varSend variable
varSend = new URLRequest(prefix + "php/myphpPage.php"); varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
varSend.data = variables;

varLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadInitialInfo); 

varLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onIOError);

var0 = var0; 
variables.sendRequest = "AAA";  

// Send the data to the php file
varLoader.load(varSend);
```

thanks a lot

Comment: is it that php is taking more time to process parameters... or flash is taking time in sending the request in the first place... you can use firebug etc to see if response is delayed or the request is not made in the first place!

Comment: It may also help to see what the PHP page is doing.

Comment: it seems I have a table that is taking 4-8 seconds to query, however the results of the php file on the browser are fast, and through the URL loader are slow... no idea why